# Problems with no valid "nodata" value

Tags: qgis, land-classification, landscape

I'm trying to use the "lecos" extension and I took an already classified image from the mapbiomas website, cut it out to my area of ​​interest, then reclassified to have in a .tif file only two classes, forest and non-forest.

When I'm going to run some landscape metrics in "lecos", it returns the following error message " The layer output.tif has no valid nodata value (no number)!"

I tried to use r.null to change the value of no data, but something is still wrong and I don't know what to do.

Does anyone have a suggested solution for my problem?

Comment: How did you change r.null? A bit of code showing your procedure would definitely help understand where this problem is creeping in.

Answer (score 1):

Micheal
r.null is one of the functions in qgis, I am an ecologist and do not know about coding. All I did was to run the function.
But it turns out that what the "lecos" extension wanted was a non-numerical value for the "nodata" cells. I changed the -999 original value of "nodata" cells to "null" and now everything is fine.
Thanks anyway and sorry for not knowing anything about coding.
Cheers